# will windows phone 8.1 silverlight app work on windows 10 Phone?

Tags: windows-10, win-phone-silverlight-8.1

I would like to know if a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app will work without any flaw on a Windows 10 phone. If I need to fix some bugs for Windows 10 phone, can I use VS2013 and a Windows 8.1 machine to fix the issues in Silverlight 8.1 solution?

Answer (score 2):

In general: Yes to both. Windows Phone Silverlight apps will run on Windows 10 Mobile, and you can continue to use Visual Studio 2013 to write and edit Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 apps.

See [Get ready for the Unified Dev Center dashboard preview and upcoming Store changes](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/05/01/get-ready-for-the-unified-dev-center-dashboard-preview-and-upcoming-store-changes/) for store changes you'll need to be aware of and may need to adjust for.

Comment: I have a follow on question. Will I be able to update the Phone Lock Screen Wallpaper with Windows 10 RT? Currently you can only do with with Silverlight 8.1 apps - it's not supported with WinRT8.